# Meaning of symbol :+: in Scala?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

What does the symbol :+: mean in Scala Programming language?

```
  object Devices {
  private[endpoints] def endpoints(myService: MyService[Future], pService: PService[Future]) =
    "devices" / (
      banDevice(myService, pService) :+:
      unbanDevice(myService, pService)
    )
```

This is the code snippet. I'm using finagle library.

- I've read that scala can have function names as symbols. Is this an example of that?
- Where do I find the defention of this finagle defined methods?
- Is it possible to override these methods?

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/finagle/finch/blob/master/docs/endpoint.md#coproduct-endpoints

Comment: It has no special meaning.  It's just the name of a method defined in one of the libraries that has been imported.

Comment: Also.. please include the details of any major library which may have influence on your question. For example - Finagle and Finch in this case.

Answer (score 5):

Scala Does not have this function , it can be inside one of the libraries that you are using. According to your code , you might be using finagle !

Hence What Peter Neyens pointed out : https://github.com/finagle/finch/blob/master/docs/endpoint.md#coproduct-endpoints.

Seems to explain what you are trying to find out.

P.s: Its just a method in one of the libraries and nothing else.

Answer (score 2):

In answer to your updated questions:

- Yes, that code is calling the function (actually a method) named `:+:`.
- You can probably find the API published online (maybe [here](https://twitter.github.io/finagle/docs/#com.twitter.finagle.package)).
- If the class is not `sealed` and the method is not `final` then, yes, you should be able to override it.